# Android:layout_weight for inner element

Tags: android, xml, android-layout-weight

I have a LinearLayout in which there are two items: ImageView at the top and horizontal LinearLayout with fixed size at the bottom.

I want to do my ImageView view fills all empty space.

So it works with:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

But now I want to wrap my ImageView by CardView like this:

```
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffd9d9d9"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Of course It doesn't work as I want. (But it should show what I want)

I want to get ImageView as in first code example but wrapped in GridView.

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Also: is there any way to center item in cardview withour using relativelayout? layout_gravity="center" doesn't work. I don't know why. (Why?)

Thank you so much.

Comment: use layout_gravity="centre" and remove android:layout_weight="1" when using linearlayout

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but first of all weight only works in LinearLayouts, and your imageView is in a Relative one. By the way, layout_gravity="center" is to be applied on the parent LinearLayout, not in the child ImageView, because it defines how children behave in the layout

Comment: liltof, yes, I know it all and so I wrote that this code is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get ImageView as in first code example but wrapped in GridView.

well your CardView is wrap_content which means its dimensions are determined after children. your ImageView has no fixed dimension so all i will say is use this

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="centerInside" // or fitCenter
      />
```

> is there any way to center item in cardview withour using relativelayout? layout_gravity="center" doesn't work. I don't know why. (Why?)

well yea as an element for your card view instead of using `layout_gravity` use just `gravity` and `center_horizontal` remove the `RelativeLayout` unless you need it then you must add centerInParent as an element of your imageview inside the RelativeLayout

Comment: CardView works correct with this. But how can I do that ImageView will match all screen width or all screen height if possible?

Comment: I know that fitCenter should ge me what I want but while imageview stills in cardview id doesn't work